# Gradient descent exploding gradient and error on known learning rates

Tags: python

I am writing a simple gradient descent function in python, and I end up with an extremely large exploding gradient and cost problem. I am fairly sure that the function follows the actual algorithm, yet I cannot think of any reason why it is doing this, especially since it does it on values for the learning rate that I know should produce valid results.

Here is the gradient descent functions:

```
def costFunc(w,X,y):
    resid = y-np.dot(X,w)
    error = np.dot(resid.T, resid) / (2*len(y))
    return error

def gradient(w,X,y):
    predY = np.dot(X, w)
    error = predY - y
    return np.dot(X.T, error) / len(y)

def gradDesc(X,y,iterations=1500,learnrate=1):
    A,B = np.shape(X)
    w = np.zeros([B,1])
    for k in range(iterations):
        grad = gradient(w,X,y)
        w = w - (learnrate * grad)
        if k  == iterations - 1:
            cost = costFunc(w,X,y)
    return w, cost
```

when run on the Boston house price dataset, it should expect an error of 31.79169332623314 after 100 iterations with a learn rate of 1. I am reaching an error of 2.22679438e+13 after 1 iteration.

Let me know if I need to provide any more code snippets.

Comment: "Let me know if I need to provide any more code snippets" yes we do. we have no clue how you call your functions, how you define your variables etc... [ask] and [mre]

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-scaler is a good friend, e.g. https://www.kaggle.com/code/shreayan98c/boston-house-price-prediction?scriptVersionId=11190449&cellId=63

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't care about normalization, which makes the output soft into a specific range.

See these lines:

```
for k in range(iterations):
    grad = gradient(w,X,y)
    w = w - (learnrate * grad)
    if k  == iterations - 1:
        cost = costFunc(w,X,y)
return w, cost
```

This loop finishes when the iteration operates 1500 times, which are making the gradient exploding. The Learning rate doesn't affect the result. The problem is that you are making almost like 1500 layers, which means it is a tremendous deep neural network. To deal with this, you should add normalization such as BN, ReLU or reduce the amount of iterations.